# Select2 multiple box placeholder not showing on hide then make it visible case

Tags: select, show-hide, placeholder, jquery-select2

I am using select2() in `<select multiple>`. What I have is a **placeholder** in that select. What I am doing is initially I am hiding the select containing div and then I am making it visible. In this case initially placeholder not showing.

If we are not doing this hide and block thing then it is working fine.

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/fyhsz9ra/447/)

Comment: I updated my answer to reflect your question. I happend to read over the "multiple" part. I provided code to solve your issue. Could you verify the solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(EDITED) Sorry I read the question wrong. I thought it was about regular selects not multiples.

I've checked your fiddle.

1. This contains 2 multiples.  `<select multiple id="e1" style="width:100%" multiple data-placeholder="Choose country(s)*">`. I don't know if this is intentional. But you should remove one.
2. The input element select2 has it's `width` set to `0px` when you set `display: none`. You need to increase the width to an appropriate size.
3. I added `$('.select2-input, .select2-default', $("#divid")).css('width', '100%');` to your code and this solved your issue.

#### Snippet (non-functional, needs select2 libraries):

```js
$("#e1").select2();
    $('.select2-input, .select2-default', $("#divid")).css('width', '100%');
    $("#divid").css("display","block");
```

```html
<div id="divid" style="display:none;">

<select id="e1" style="width:100%" multiple data-placeholder="Choose country(s)*">
        <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
        <option value="Am">Amalapuram</option>
        <option value="An">Anakapalli</option>
        <option value="Ak">Akkayapalem</option>
        <option value="WY">Wyoming</option>
    </select>     
</div>
```

Comment: Dude you are genius! I've been searching for a fix for so long as I thought the issue is coming from a completely different reason. Never thought to look things up from css point of view. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

just add this class in your .css file.
.select2-search__field{width:100% !important;}